# Java applet fails to reload on Internet Explorer

Tags: java, applet

I have an applet that has a `logout"`button. The button ends the session by calling a CGI script and then kills Java VM by calling `System.exit()`. The problem is when a user tries to log in again in the same browser window - the applet fails to load with `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
load: class lucent/fm/parts/BlankPage.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lucent.fm.parts.BlankPage.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://example.com/html/lucent/fm/parts/BlankPage/class.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 7 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lucent.fm.parts.BlankPage.class
```

It appears only on Internet Explorer, not in Firefox. Java Plugin is:
`Java Plug-in 1.6.0_20

Using JRE version 1.6.0_20-b02 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM`

**The direct scenario is the following**:
1. Log in to the system (load the applet).
2. Log out (it closes the applet, but the browser window persists).
3. Click on the address bar and press Enter.
4. The applet fails to load and the `ClassNotFoundException` can be seen in Java Console.
5. Refresh the page - the server redirects to the login page; after logging in, the applet again does not load and throws the exception.

Looking at the Apache access log proved that in the step 4 that the browser (or plugin) tries to load jar files and gets a HTTP error. It is OK because the session has expired. The strange thing happens in the 5th point - there is no request for jars! It seems that the browser or plugin remembers failed attempts and does not even try to load jar files. It only tries to load a raw .class file, which is not present on the server.

Is my conclusion correct? How can I deal with such an error? Is it possible to force Java plugin to load jar files?

I checked that enabling caching in Java Control Panel does not help. Setting the `codebase_lookup` parameter to `"false"` is not helpful, too. It only prevents from trying to load the `"class"` file directly.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Your error looks like the something tried to load the class named `lucent.fm.parts.BlankPage.class`, which is an illegal class name (it should be `lucent.fm.parts.BlankPage`, I suppose). The question is, why does your browser/Plugin try to load this class?

Comment: It is because the HTML page: <PARAM NAME = CODE VALUE="lucent/fm/parts/BlankPage.class">; I could change it to BlankPage instead of BlankPage.class, but it does not help. 
According to the official documentation, the class name should be with ".class" suffix: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html

Answer (score 2):

> I have an applet that has a "logout" button. The button ends the session by calling a CGI script and then kills Java VM by calling System.exit().

An applet calling `System.exit(anyNumber)` is crudely equivalent to a guest burning down the house of their host.  Applets (even trusted applets) should **never** try to end the VM.  The VM will be ended by the browser when all applets in a page that share the VM have finished their `destroy()` methods and a subsequent period of time as chosen by the browser.

BTW - I recall one version of Mozilla/FF where calling `System.exit(int)` not just ended the VM, but also crashed the browser!

Comment: As far as I know, closing the browser when System.exit is called was a normal behavior before Sun introduced "next generation Java plug-in".

Comment: @pkalinow:  Thanks for the further info.  After trying it once I decided it was something never to try again.  I'm glad the new plug-in refuses the request.  Browsers have a perfectly functional **`X`** button to close them (or whatever it is on your OS/browser), they do not need the help of an applet.

Comment: The problem with `x` button is that it does not close all the windows in the current session and does not remove the session cookie. These two requirements I have to fulfill.

Comment: Do that from the applet `destroy()` method.  If you want a button to `Exit Applet`, redirect to a 'Thanks for using our applet' page.  The `destroy()` method should be called be the browser/JRE combo.  BTW - I am surprised that crashing the browser removes the cookie.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I need to close all my applets in the current session, not only the one which has been clicked.
Regarding cookies - session cookies are being destroyed after closing the browser.

Comment: @pkalinow "I need to close all my applets in the current session, not only the one which has been clicked."  So extrapolate the advice I provided re. `destroy()` to *each* applet.  *Any* applet that redirects to another page, will cause the invocation of the `destroy()` method of *every* applet on the page.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: sorry, I don't understand. What should I do with `destroy()` method? And how can it help?

Answer (score 1):

If your html with applets is not static (cgi, php, etc), then after logging out, you can try to force different URL pointing to the jar file (i.e. instead of "my.jar" use "my.jar?random=1235232").

Also, you can try to play with cache HTTP headers.

Another potential workaround will be to reconfigure apache to serve the jars always - even when session has been closed (if that's acceptable).